# How does a network cryptor work?

Tags: routing, layer2, layer3, layer1

I want to know at which layer is a network cryptor used. What are the features of routers used for encrypted packets?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  There are many types of encryptors and they work at different layers.  Routers commonly use IPSec tunnels to encrypt traffic.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encryption can be deployed at almost all layers of the networking stack - some examples to research would include:

- Layer 1/Physical Layer: Optical encryption
- Layer 2/Logical-Link Layer: MACSec, 802.1x, WPA
- Layer 3/Network Layer: IPSEC, L2TP
- Layer 7/Application Layer: TLS

For a router, you would most likely need one that supports IPSEC

Comment: Worth adding - MACSEC is becoming more common on routers (ex: Cisco ASR, newer Arista gear) and is a nice way to do hop-by-hop encryption.